# Magento 2: how to delete orders from the database

Tags: database, orders, magento2.2.2

How can I delete the test orders created in my store?
I have opened the database but I couldn't find the order table.
Please help me to delete the orders.
I'm using the later version of Magento 2.

Answer (score 20):

You can delete all the orders, order history, shipments, invoices, credit memos, also the quotes, quote items  from database by following SQL:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

**# Clean order history**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;
```

**# Clean order infos**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
```

## Clean cart infos

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
```

## If tax enable in store

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;
```

#Reset indexes (if you want your orders number start back to 1

```
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_invoice_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_order_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_shipment_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_creditmemo_1;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Before doing above take a backup of your database.

Hope this will help.

Also a good overview: https://gist.github.com/sjovanig/3c18d687c60bb39cd752ce63db5d72f7

Comment: What if I want to delete particular orders, not all?

Comment: You check the entity id of those and delete those accordingly. Also if you want to use extension then you can try https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-delete-orders

Comment: I hope the extension is free?

Comment: Extension url is from GitHub. So it's free to download.

Comment: I saw that, I just wanted to be sure. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding

Comment: I have downloaded the magento-2-delete extension from mageplaza. how to set up it on my store @SukumarGorai

Comment: Create folder Mageplaza/DeleteOrders under app/code and post all the codes under it. This extension also requires Mageplaza core,this is the module url https://github.com/mageplaza/module-core install it like same.

Comment: I got below error when i try above queries:

Error:  #1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`UIL`.`sales_creditmemo_comment`, CONSTRAINT `SALES_CREDITMEMO_COMMENT_PARENT_ID_SALES_CREDITMEMO_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `UIL`.`sales_creditmemo` (`entity_id`))

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you to avoid direct mess with SQL.

You can use any good extension like [Mageplaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-delete-orders/)

Another option is to create a script on root and delete order programmatically

You can create a file at root with following code:

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$ids = array(1,2,3,4); // your order_id 

foreach ($ids as $id) {

    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
    $registry->register('isSecureArea','true');
    $order->delete();
    $registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
    echo "order deleted";

}
```

**Edit I**

If you want to delete order using script you can put above code on root folder of magento.After that you can hit URL in browser.

For example your magento is installed at www.example.com and your file name is `deleteOrder.php` you can run it by:

```
 www.example.com/deleteOrder.php
```

If you want to install extension you need to

```
- Extract folder at [magentoRoot]/app/code
- Open terminal and run cd [magentoRoot] //change to root dir
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (only required in production mode)
```

You can also find document at [Official Site](https://docs.mageplaza.com/delete-order-m2/index.html)

Comment: But that is not free, right?

Comment: Module I shared is free, if you don't want to go with module simply use one time script.

Comment: because once we delete dummy order, we will rarely use that extension.

Comment: Welcome @ElishaSenoo. Are you going with module Or script ?

Comment: I am going with module for now.

Comment: Great, You can up-vote answer if it help you :)

Comment: @Pawan guide me installing script or module. I have downloaded mageplaze extension. what I have to do next...

Comment: Hello @SalesforceElearner, please see my update in original Answer.

Comment: @Pawan I used your script, my orders are deleted. but two orders still present those are created based on guest user how to delete them.

Comment: Please try again with only those 2 order id

Comment: Please also check any log for error

Comment: I used your script and deleted the orders but data are still here if we check order  reports

Comment: Great solution ! it works fine on magento 2.2.x

Comment: @VuTranKien, glad to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to remove all invoices,shipments,creditmemos of the order first.

```
$incrementId = 10000342;
$order       = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
//or
//$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea','true');

$invoices    = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    $invoice->delete();
}
$shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
foreach ($shipments as $shipment) {
    $shipment->delete();
}
$creditmemos = $order->getCreditmemosCollection();
foreach ($creditmemos as $creditmemo) {
    $creditmemo->delete();
}
// delete invoices/shipments/creditmemos & then finally delete order
$order->delete();
$registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
```

Answer (score 0):

in case Anyone still interested in this, i did it without installing any extension, steps:

- download n98-magerun2 from github https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2
- run this to access dev console : **./n98-magerun2.phar  dev:console --area=frontend**
- run this script

  ```
   $registry = $di->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
   $startId = 1;
   $endId = 7000;
   for ($i = $startId; $i < $endId; $i++) {
       try {
           $order = $di->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($i);
           $registry->register('isSecureArea', 'true');
           $order->delete();
           $registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
           echo "order deleted";
       } catch (\Exception $th) {
           //throw $th;
       }
   }
  ```

change start and end id