# Exception error in claue theme

Tags: theme, magento2.4

I am having an error while working on claue theme on magento 2.4 after installation.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/code/MGS/PurchasedProduct/view/frontend/templates/recentorder.phtml on line 63
```

***I am working on maching that is : centos/lampp stack./elasticsuite***

Any help please.?

Comment: Could you please paste the content of that phtml file? Without seeing the content, you cannot receive any type of help.

Comment: Started working after deleting orders from database directly otherwise I have to disable to module. thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way to solve this error by deleting orders form database directly: as answer from here.

[Deleting orders from database magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242334/magento-2-how-to-delete-orders-from-the-database/242337)

but welcome if any other way to solve this problem .

Thank You.