# Magento 2 : Delete order programmatically

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I am working on to create an a controller
in its execute method the order id will be passed & using that order id the order will be deleted permanently from magento.

is their any way to delete order permanently from magento.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242334/magento-2-how-to-delete-orders-from-the-database/242337#242337

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize php script to delete orders manually. Go to the file manager on your server and generate a deleteorder.php file with the command below:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$ids = array(00123,00456,000453,0002544); // insert your order IDs here, separte by comma
foreach ($ids as $id) {
   $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
   $registry->register('isSecureArea','true');
   $order->delete();
   $registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
   echo "order deleted";
}
```

You can apply above code in your controller and delete the order by id as per above way.

Comment: Using this method & passing order id in it. This won't create issue anywhere in shipment for this order,credit memo etc if accessed from admin?

Comment: It will delete your order completely

Comment: ok, this won't create issue anywhere in shipment for this order,credit memo etc if accessed from admin?

Comment: Yes it will not create an issue

Comment: @ZealousWeb using object manager is not recommended could you please update your answer to use as di ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following function from `vendor/magento/module-sales/Api/OrderRepositoryInterface.php`

```
/**
 * Deletes a specified order.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $entity The order ID.
 * @return bool
 */
public function delete(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $entity);
```

Comment: Using this method & passing order id in it.
This won't create issue anywhere in shipment for this order,credit memo etc ?

Comment: @devhs Not sure, you can try it out, if it fulfils your requirement without breaking your existing functionalities.